# Dynamically add routes in golang http

Tags: go

I am trying to read routes from json and appending them to mux , but instead of appending it seems to overwrite routes.

Code snippet

```
 func main() {

    configLoader()

    dispatchMux := http.NewServeMux()

    for _, site := range ServerConfigData.Sites {
        append(dispatchMux, site.Incomming, site.Forward)
    }

    // Start the server

    color.Green("Server Spinned Up on 2096")
    http.ListenAndServe(":2096", dispatchMux)
}

 // Route Appender
 func append(mux *http.ServeMux, incomming, forward string) {
        color.Yellow("Starting ", incomming, " on ", forward, "\n")
        parsedURL, _ := url.Parse(forward)
        mux.Handle(incomming, httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(parsedURL))
}
```

Comment: You need to have a global reference to the server object, refer to it in one of your route handlers

Comment: What are the values of `incoming`?

Comment: "incomming":"/a"

Comment: You shouldn't name a function `append` as it conflicts with the [built-in function `append`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices).

Comment: Don't know reason, but when i moved code of append inside for loop its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func main() {

    configLoader()

    dispatchMux := http.NewServeMux()

    for _, site := range ServerConfigData.Sites {

        //Previously code of append function
        parsedURL, _ := url.Parse(site.Forward)
        fmt.Println(site.Incomming)
        dispatchMux.Handle(site.Incomming, httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(parsedURL))

    }    
    // Start the server    
    color.Green("Server Spinned Up on 2096")
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", dispatchMux)
}
```